# How to pass Javascript LocalStorage Value in PUG

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

I am getting Error while parsing Json LocalStorage variable in PUG/JADE

```html
extends base.pug

block style
    style
        include ../static/trendbar.css

block scripts
    //- script(src="../static/jquery.js")
    //- script(src="../static/jquery2.js")

block content
    script!= "var items = []; items =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('obj')); console.log(items);"     
    .product
        h3.trendbar
            | Trending
        .row#loadProduct
            - var items1 = items;
            each n,i in items1
                .column
                    a.itemcon#cursor(href="/p/"+n.PID )
                        .pitem
                            .pitemMage
                                - var img = "../static/hookah/" + n.PID + ".jpg"
                                img(src= img alt ='NO MORE PRODUCT')
                            .pitemAvail
                                |   #{n.availability}
                            .pitemCost
                                p.prod_name
                                    |  #{n.name}
                                .prod_price
                                    p.realP
                                        |  ₹#{n.Mprice}
                                    p.ourP
                                        |  ₹#{n.Oprice}
```

TypeError: F:\hookahboi\views\trending.pug:18
16|         .row#loadProduct

```
17|             - var items1 = items;
```

> 18|             each n,i in items1

```
19|                 .column

20|                     a.itemcon#cursor(href="/p/"+n.PID )

21|                         .pitem
```

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at eval (eval at wrap (F:\hookahboi\node_modules\pug-runtime\wrap.js:6:10), :188:32)
at eval (eval at wrap (F:\hookahboi\node_modules\pug-runtime\wrap.js:6:10), :279:4)
at template (eval at wrap (F:\hookahboi\node_modules\pug-runtime\wrap.js:6:10), :340:7)

Comment: Pug templates are processed server-side. LocalStorage is client-side, in the browser. These are two completely different things, on two completely separate machines, that execute at different times. There is no way Pug can simply access the localStorage. Please see the difference between server-side and client-side programming.

Comment: so is there any way to store and display localstorage data, I am using Pug,Nodejs and  I really dont know that pug is ServerSide.

Comment: I know you are using Pug and Nodejs. "Is there any way to store and display local storage data" in Pug, please read again my previous comment, I believe the answer is very clear.

Comment: Imagine you write a letter. The letter says, "Dear sir, please write here the names of your children : ______________". Then you fold the letter, send the letter by post mail. Then the person receives the letter and then writes the names of their children on the paper. See? There is NO WAY you could read the names of the children _before_ the person writes them three days later. This is _exactly_ what you are trying to do now with Pug. You are trying to display data that will exist later in time, in a different house, written by a different person with a different pen.

Comment: i already save some json data to LocalStorage. if i knew That Pug is server Side Then i dont waste so much time on it. Thanks for Saving my time , now i will learn something new technique that i could use to solve this issue. thanks once again

Comment: You don't know that you are writing server-side code? So you don't know if you are the person writing the letter or the person receiving the letter? :) Anyway you're welcome, programming is such a vast and complicated matter.